# Bootstrap dropdown menu appears as a normal nav-link

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a base bootstrap site for my school project, and it went quite well, until i wanted to add a dropdown menu. So as of now the dropdown behaves, as a default nav-link, even though i literally ctrl+c and ctrl+v-d it from the official bootstrap documentation. Later on i copy pasted the entire example nav and for the lack of the better word it [shat](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/749562089659695125/798453272414388234/unknown.png) itself completely.

after reading the code over and over i gave up, and came here for your help!

heres the code:

```css
.navbar{
    margin:0;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width:100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-radius: 0;
}

footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Recipeheaven</title>
    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--JQuery-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--My own CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
            </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
    </header>
    <footer>
        <footer class="bg-light text-center text-lg-start">
            <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)">
              © 2020 Copyright:
              <a class="text-dark" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/">MDBootstrap.com</a>
            </div>
          </footer>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have updated the code, just copy it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your secondary closing `</li>` tag and move your jQuery script tag above your bootstrap script tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Recipeheaven</title>
    <!--JQuery-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--My own CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
    </header>
    <footer>
        <footer class="bg-light text-center text-lg-start">
            <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)">
              © 2020 Copyright:
              <a class="text-dark" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/">MDBootstrap.com</a>
            </div>
          </footer>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xam5g8hb/ | I do not know what is in your main.js file, however, here is a link to a working fiddle.

Comment: nothing, haven't done anything with it yet

Answer (score 0):

**You are using the link dropdown and not the button dropdown:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Recipeheaven</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--My own CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown button
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <footer>
      <footer class="bg-light text-center text-lg-start">
        <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)">
          © 2020 Copyright:
          <a class="text-dark" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/">MDBootstrap.com</a>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/XWjxbmB?editors=1000

Comment: it changed into a button, but still doesn't do the "dropdowning"

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @Cr4ckTh3Skye can you share your complete code so far

Comment: its in there. i have an empty main.js i haven't share and thats it

Comment: @Cr4ckTh3Skye I have updated the code, just completely copy it into your file, it will work for sure.

Comment: nope. when i click on it nothing happens.what the heck is going on here?

Comment: Have you copied the whole code or just code inside body.

Comment: The code you have provided is not of bootstrap's latest version.

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Comment: Visual Studio Code has an extension called `Live Share`. By Microsoft. Install it and send me the link, so that we can share the code live with each other.

Comment: https://prod.liveshare.vsengsaas.visualstudio.com/join?839F9AE60EECEEB38D12A77A919E49151A52

Comment: i reckon you can't see my comments, i do reply to all of your questions there. it doesn't work with your edit

Comment: @Cr4ckTh3Skye I don't know what happened I was able to see all of them, can you send another link

Comment: The code was working fine when used in my pc.

Comment: might be some technical issue

Comment: If you are online, then send me a new link